# How to hide labels by two ticks? chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

How can we customize labels and hide it 2 ticks/line (see the expected output below)? I already tried the code below but it did nothing. Is there any chance we can hide it specifically?

```
legend: {
   labels: {
      filter: function(label) {
         if (label.text === '10' || label.text === 10) return false;
      }
   }
},
```

Here is my working code like [click link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-darkness-x31u7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/index.js)

---

**Current Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517956/onclick-event-to-hide-dataset-chart-js-v2 try that link, I thought it's similar to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.callback` function

```
render() {
    const options = {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      type: "bar",
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
              if (index % 2 === 0) {
                return value;
              }
              return null;
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    };
}
```

Comment: almost Sir, your code hide first one tick label. Can you try to remove the first two ticks label like the example above?

Comment: Just use `index % 3 === 0` instead of `index % 2 === 0`

Comment: You should return `null`, not `""`. See my answer.

Comment: @DarkTrick, thanks for clarification! I will update the response

Answer (score 1):

Note: @Catalin 's answer is problematic. Problem: He/She is returning `""` in case the label should be hidden. However, you should return `null`.

## Generalized answer

You need to use the  [`options.scales.yAxes.ticks.callback` function](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.1.0/api/interfaces/tickoptions.html#callback)

```
const options = {
  scales:{
    yAxes: {
      ticks: {
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          if (index % 2 === 0) {
            return value;
          }
          return null; // <- NOT ""
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

#### Why is `null` so important?

The impact becomes clear on the xAxes:
Returning `null` tells chartjs that *there is no label*. 
[image: example when null is returned]

Returning `""` tells chartjs that *there is a label*. That means, it reserves space. In this case the labels are slanted:
[image: example when an empty string is returned]